# What does 'to draw' mean here as a verb?

Tags: meaning

What does 'to draw' mean here as a verb?

> NMU’s four-year degree is the closest thing to a degree in marijuana
>   at an accredited university in the United States. It **has drawn** nearly
>   300 students from 48 states, Canfield said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Verb means the following:

to bring toward oneself or itself, as by inherent force or influence; attract:

Put simply:

> Attract